# How to show multiple images at one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, slider

I use jquery cycle slider and need to show 3 images in one slide and slide one image every time. I have searched for way but I cannot find one.
What is the best slider I can use or how to use cycle to do that?

This image show what I need:

[image: slider example]

```
$('.my-of-slide').cycle({
    fx:'scrollLeft',
    next:'.glyphicon-chevron-right',
    prev:'.glyphicon-chevron-left',
});
```

Comment: Well, you didn't search for too long, did you now. Anyway, you may be looking for a carousel. Like this. http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/

Comment: It looks like jQuery Cycle is deprecated in favour of Cycle2. As @Roope mentions, what you're trying to implement is called a 'carousel', Cycle2's documentation contains everything you need: [http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php)